# Adding a Line Break to Strings

Tags: c++, string, newline

I am writing a program that lets the user input some advice on coding. I am having trouble getting the program to add a line break after each new line. I am able to append a space just fine, but I can't seem to get a line break in there. Any advice?

```
void add_new_advice(Advice& advice)
{
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

    // read and concatenate lines until two newlines are read
    while (getline(cin, advice.advice))
    {
        if (advice.advice.empty()) break;

        else advice.newAdvice += advice.advice + " ";
    }

    cout << advice.newAdvice;

    return;
}
```

Comment: append a "\n" for a newline. or "\n\r" if in Windows

Comment: Hmmm, I tried both of those but neither works. I am using Visual Studio 2013. could that be the problem?

Comment: You need to explain how you determine that "neither works", since they in fact do.

Comment: I have added the '+ "/n" ' as well as '+ "/n/r" ' to the code and it prints the actual letters '/n' '/n/r' to the console.

Comment: why you are using ignore? just get lines until you've got an empty one.

Comment: Thanks jay that was the problem. I feel like an idiot!

Comment: The ignore was to clear the the input buffer from previous entries earlier in the program.

Comment: @Sayutee It's `\r\n` *not* `\n\r` on Windows.

Comment: OOPS Sorry. Thanks @Snps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line break is just a special character `\n`, but may be interpreted differently under different OS, check this wiki page for more details about [NewLine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

However, when it comes to code, simply append `\n` behind your strings and then the compiler will convert it properly based on your OS and write it into the file.

For your information, you can check [Escaped Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) to get familiar with.

Comment: It's `\n` on any platform. The text stream will convert it to `\r\n` if needed on output.

Comment: Oh `\r\n` means when you are reading a new line, the `return` will be treated as `\r\n`

Comment: No. `\r\n` is written in the file, but `cin` and `cout` work with `\n` only and do the conversion automatically.

Comment: I retracted my downvote after the edit, but the mention of `\r\n` in the first line is still confusing and borderline wrong.

Comment: thanks for your advise, please check the latest edit and see if appropriate.